# Highlight all cells in range which contain values from another range

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need to highlight all cells in range(r) which contain values from another range(dictionary).

This code only highlights first occurrences of each cell in the dictionary range.

```vb
Sub SearchAndFormat_Click()   
    Dim Dictionary As Variant
    Dictionary = Range("L5:L9")
    
    Dim r As Range, cell As Variant
    Set r = Application.InputBox("Select range", "Selection Window", Type:=8)
    r.ClearFormats
    r.NumberFormat = "General"
    
    For Each subj In Dictionary
        For Each cell In r
            Set target_cell = r.Find(subj, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not target_cell Is Nothing Then
                target_cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I used to have a version of code without nested loop, but it would only highlight the first occurrence of the first value in the dictionary range.

```
For Each cell In r
    Set target_cell = r.Find(Dictionary, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not target_cell Is Nothing Then
        target_cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Find` in order find all values equal to the target, then it should be sort of a `Do ... Loop` with active use of a parameter `After:=...` For example:

```
Set x = MyRange.Find(target)
If Not x Is Nothing Then
   Start = x.Address
   Do
      Debug.Print x.Address, x.Value
      Set x = MyRange.FindNext(After:=x)
   Loop While x.Address <> Start
End If
```

But there's no need to use `Find` when you loop through each value in a dictionary and in a range of interest:

```
Sub test_colorizing()
Dim d As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim x, y
    Set d = Range(...)   ' Dictionary
    Set r = Range(...)   ' Range of interest
    For Each x In r
        For Each y In d
            If x = y Then
                x.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                Exit For   ' go to the next word in r
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

How it can look with `Find`:

```
Sub test_colorizing_with_find()
Dim dict As Range    ' Dictionary
Dim rng As Range     ' Range of interest
Dim cell, word, start
    Set dict = Range(...)
    Set rng = Range(...)
    For Each word In dict
        Set cell = rng.Find(word)
        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            start = cell.Address
            Do
               cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
               Set cell = rng.FindNext(cell)
            Loop While cell.Address <> start
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the find option works pefectly. The x=y didnt work as i need only a partial match (the value in rng begins with the value from dict). Still not quite sure what exactly it does though, as it is complex, with few loops.

Comment: @Kensain Instead of `x=y` we can use `x like (y & "*")` where x is a cell in `rnd` and `y` is a word in `dict`. Or we could use `InStr(1, cell, word) = 1` as well.